# Do I need a "with" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis, indirect-objects, prepositional-objects, ditransitivity

Usually, I know the answer. But the following sentence confuses me:

> Was he the man she had shared her flesh and feelings (with) for four
>   years?

Is the *with* necessary? Why or why not?

Comment: Would you say _I shared my thoughts him_ or _I shared him my thoughts_ or _I shared my thoughts with him_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

In given sentence you mentioned a person the thing is shared with so it's natural to use such collocation.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon 'with' must be used for completeness, and for the sentence to be meaningful.

Also the sentence becomes incorrect if you remove the word 'with'.